# Check for valid dates for all steps of the date

Tags: regex

I want to check if a given string is a date of the form YYYY-mm-dd, including all the steps in it, i.e. YYYY-mm-dd, YYYY-mm and YYYY.

For example, all of the following dates are valid:

```
2014

2014-07

2014-07-03
```

This is my current regex:

```
^\d{4}(:?-\d{1,2}(:?-\d{1,2})?)?$
```

Is it OK?

Comment: What language or framework is this regex used in?

Comment: Why do you allow single-digit days and months? That doesn't match your description.

Comment: @Reinderien JavaScript, oh they were just examples, single digits is also allowed

Answer (score 1):

> Is it OK?

Yes.

In the sense that it is "correct". It matches your stated specification, as amended to include both single- and double-digit months and days.

Is it maintainable?

No, in a setting where multiple engineers who come and go
will work on the code, it is less maintainable than this regex:

```
^\d{4}(-\d{1,2}){0,2}$
```

which in turn is less maintainable than this one:

```
^\d{4}(-\d{1,2})?(-\d{1,2})?$
```

> Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.
>
> -- Abelson & Sussman, [SICP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs)

The last regex immediately conveys the notion of y-m-d
to a newly hired engineer at a glance,
in a way that the other formulations do not.